# How to change width of a sidebar in docusaurus

Tags: docusaurus

I want to change the sidebar width in docusaurus, I am only allowed to change the width of sidebar in a particular page.Can anyone suggest me a solution

Answer (score 8):

In version ~2.0.0 you can [create your own CSS files](https://docusaurus.io/docs/styling-layout) (/src/css/custom.css) by defining it in the `docusaurus.config.js`. There you can set your override styles. When inspecting the page, there's Docusaurus sets the variable for `--doc-sidebar-width: 300px;` I was able to override that variable with an `!important`:

```
:root { 
    --doc-sidebar-width: 250px !important;
}
```

Comment: This will work but will affect all the pages right? I need to adjust the sidebar width for only one page